# when i press Enter without give any value, i expect return to me the first case but it give to me the second case

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Program
{
    class Pro
    {
        static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            var names = new List<string>();
            var Line = Console.ReadLine().Split();

            foreach (var item in Line)
            {
                names.Add(item);
            }

            switch (names.Count)
            {
                case 0:
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    Console.WriteLine(names[0] + "Likes your post");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Console.WriteLine(names[0] + "and" + names[1] + "Likes your post");
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine(names[0] + " and " + names[1] + " and "
                        + (names.Count - 2)+"Likes your post");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Because `Split` returns one empty string item. You always get number of separators + 1 items as result. In this case number of spaces (=0) + 1 = 1 items.

Comment: `Split` will return an empty string. Use the overload `Split(new[] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);` But what's the use of adding the array elements to a list?

Answer (score 1):

You should use this Split method option : `RemoveEmptyEntries` in order to remove empty string, as @ZorgoZ said.

Something like this:

`var line = Console.ReadLine().Split(new[] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);`

With this option, you should get the first case in your switch statement.

You can read more about [String.Split Method here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Answer (score 0):

i have not tested your code neither have i experienced this specific issue. But my educated guess would be that it is adding "" (empty string) to your list. i would suggest that you print each entry to console when you add it to the list... just to see what it is adding to the list. And then if you  want to fix it make sure you skip entries with empty string by comparing it to "" and skipping the add instruction if it is found to be empty

Let me know how it goes.